# Migrate content to new domain without 301 redirects

Tags: search

I have a domain name http://extreme-java.com purchased from one.com and pointing to my web hosting account at anhosting.com

I want to move the content of this website to http://somenewdomain.com registered at godaddy.com by making the new domain point to the same web hosting account.

Just planning to close the extreme-java domain as it has got a lot of spam backlinks.
As per google guidelines about migrating content, they suggest 301 redirects from current domain to get the juice but is it necessary to use 301 redirect in my case as I simply want to dump the extreme-java domain

Pls advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind starting from scratch, giving up all your links, bookmarks, people who remember the url and pagerank then sure you don't need 301 redirects. If you want to keep any of that then you are going to need to keep the old domain running and 301 redirect the important urls to the same pages on the new site.

Since importance is based on links to your site as well as the content itself, when you cut off links inevitably you will lose pagerank. Ranking will always tend towards what is appropriate for your content, it is just a case of where you start from.

Comment: It might also be worth telling Google that your site has moved using Webmaster Tools (under 'Site Configuration', 'Change of Address'), if only to prevent getting penalized for duplicate content.

Comment: And what will happen to the pages present in google search cache for the current domain. Am I right in assuming that they will go away with time and the content from new website will get indexed?

Comment: there is no penalty for duplicate content. But if you do a change of address, maybe Google will transfer the accumulated data from the old to the new one

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the rel="canonical" tag. I say might because it is used more as a hint by the search engines rather then an absolute.

The following link more information of the tag:

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394